# how to run function javascript when onload pageand the some time Check ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to know if this function is correct i want to run function ParseJSON1; / ParseJSON2; when window.onload this my first day with javascript

```
function langue() { 
 var english = document.getElementById('lang_link\\[en\\]'').value;
 var french = document.getElementById('lang_link\\[fr\\]'').value;

     if( english == 'fr' ) {
         window.onload = function()
          { 
            ParseJSON1;
          } 
    else {
        window.onload = function()
          { 
            ParseJSON2;
          } 
      }
```

Comment: No...you wouldn't using `window.onload` inside the function and you aren't calling `ParseJSON1()` or `ParseJSON2()`..note the `()` needed

Comment: so how do to change this code

Comment: `if( english == 'fr'){ ParseJSON1() } else...`